# model reference in the angular directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Angular 15. for some reason I'm not able to get a reference to the ngModel in the custom directive. I'm trying to build a custom directive, which trims the input value (before the validation) and triggers the data changed event (to update the model). Currently I can change the actual value of the input element, however I'm not able to trigger the input value changed event nor access the actual model.
To summarise, there are few issues: 1) can't obtain a reference to the actual ngModel within the custom directive. 2) can't trigger the input value changed event to update the model accordingly. 3) this.ngModel.model is always undefined for some reason.
Here is the custom directive:

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Input, ChangeDetectorRef, Output, ElementRef, HostListener, Inject, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][appCustomDirective]',
  providers: [NgModel]
})
export class CustomDirective {
  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private ngModel: NgModel) { }

   @HostListener("blur")
   onBlur() {
    //let value = this.ngModel.model;
    let value = this.elementRef.nativeElement.value;

    if(value) {
      value = value.trim();
      this.renderer.setProperty(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, "value", value);
      this.renderer.setAttribute(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, "value", value);
      this.ngModel.update.emit(value);
    } else {
      this.renderer.setProperty(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, "value", null);
      this.renderer.setAttribute(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, "value", "");
      this.ngModel.update.emit("");
    }
  }
}
```

please advice, I have tried different approaches and ways to do that but neither of those worked. In the code above, the reference to the model is just a stub, it's not the actual model that needs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

the workaround was to add reference to the FormControl or the NgControl. When having reference to the FormControl, it's easy to set the modified value and trigger the model update.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomDirective]'
})
export class CustomDirective {

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private control : NgControl) { }

  @HostListener("keyup")
  onKeyup() {
    let value = this.elementRef.nativeElement.value;
    const abstractControl = this.control.control;

    if(value && (value.startsWith(' ') || value.endsWith(' '))) {
        abstractControl?.setValue((value || '').trim());
      }
  }
}
```